# MMS delivery reports in Google Messages?

Tags: mms, google-messages, samsung-messages

*Google Messages* is nice, but there’s that one thing that’s a killer for me : *not being able to ask for MMS delivery reports*.

To make things clear, I know that sending back an MMS delivery report is done by the user equipment (contrary to SMS delivery reports that are the provider’s job), and some just don’t, most infamously the iPhones ; so of course it won’t work when communicating with those devices, but for those that honor MMS delivery report requests, which seems to be the vast majority of Android devices, I would like to be able to ask for one.

I have a Samsung phone. On the *Samsung Messages* app it’s possible to ask for MMS delivery reports, but I don’t see such an option on *Google Messages*… is there such an option hidden somewhere (through ADB maybe ?), or is it completely absent ?

Comment: Google Messages is Google's closed-sourced app, not a stock app on Android Open Source Project. As such, I don't think there's a hidden setting other than what's shown on the in-app settings...

Comment: This _used to_ be a setting within Google Messages, but after reading your question, I've noticed it's not there anymore. It's possible it's contained within the "Service messages" setting under the "Advanced" settings section, but I'm unable to determine if that's true, or if this is a setting that has to do with marketing/business/emergency messages.

Comment: @AndrewT. Maybe in the app’s data folder ? I’ll have to “vi” through this at some point. After all, _Google Messages_ users still have their phones send back delivery reports.

Comment: @jlehenbauer I don’t have a _Service Messages_ setting in _Google Messages_ advanced settings section, but I doubt it would be there anyway, since SMS delivery reports are somewhere else.